# C makefile with subfolders and several .c files (error. ld)

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a makefile for my project but it's not working at all.
I have the following directory structure

```
projectroot
   |
   |-----main.c
   |
   |-----makefile
   |
   |-----folder1
   |       |
   |       |-----Foobar1.c
   |       |-----Foo1.c
   |       |-----Bar1.c
   |       |-----Foobar1.h
   |
   |-----folder2
   |       |-----Foo2.c
   |       |-----Foo2.h
```

Foo1.c and Bar1.c are used in Foobar1.c and they are included in the Foobar.h and it workes if i run them (Foobar1.c) in the folder1 directory.

The main.c is useing functions from both Foobar1.c and Foo2.c

```
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LIBS = -lm
all: run

run: main.o Foobar1.o Foo2.o
    $(CC) main.o Foobar1.o Foo2.o -o run $(LIBS)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c $(LIBS)

Foobar1.o: folder1/Foobar1.c folder1/Foo1.c folder1/Bar1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) folder1/Foobar1.c folder1/Foo1.c folder1/Bar1.c $(LIBS)

Foo2.o: folder2/Foo2.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) folder2/Foo2.c $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -rf *o run
```

I tried to create a Makefile for whole project in the root directory and I got this error:

```
gcc -Wall main.c -lm
gcc -Wall folder1/Foobar1.c folder1/Foo1.c folder1/Bar1.c -lm
gcc -Wall folder2/Foo2.c  -lm
gcc main.o Foobar1.o Foo2.o -o run -lm

Foobar.o: In function 'Foo1_func1':
Foobar.c: (.text+0x0): multiple definitions of 'Foo1_func1'
main.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here

Foobar.o: In function 'Bar1_func1':
Foobar.c: (.text+0x6a4): multiple definitions of 'Bar1_func1'
main.o:main.c:(.text+0x6a4): first defined here

Foobar.o: In function 'Bar1_func2':
Foobar.c: (.text+0xed8): multiple definitions of 'Bar1_func2'
main.o:main.c:(.text+0xed8): first defined here

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:13: recipe for target "run" failed
make: *** [run] error 1
```

and I also tried to create a makefile for each sub-folder and one in the root directory it did work for the sub-makefile but I don't know how to write the root makefile I tried with this

in folder1

```
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LIBS = -lm
all: bar

bar: Foobar1.o
    $(CC) Foobar1.o -o bar $(LIBS)
Foobar1.o: Foobar1.c Foo1.c Bar1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Foobar1.c $(LIBS)
clean:
    rm -rf *o bar
```

in folder2

```
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LIBS = -lm
all: foo

foo: Foo2.o
    $(CC) Foo2.o -o bar $(LIBS)
Foo2.o: Foo2.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Foo2.c $(LIBS)
clean:
    rm -rf *o foo
```

and in the root directory. is it the correct way to do this?

```
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LIBS = -lm
all:
    +$(MAKE) -C folder1
    +$(MAKE) -C folder2
run: main.o folder1/Foobar1.o folder2/Foo2.o
    $(CC) main.o folder1/Foobar1.o folder2/Foo2.o -o run $(LIBS)
main.o: main.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c $(LIBS)
clean:
    rm -rf *o run
```

Please help, it is my first time to write a makefile.

Comment: "Foo1.c and Bar1.c are used in Foobar1.c and they are included in the Foobar.h" You call your include files *.c?

Comment: It can be done with only one make file. I think you need to create intermediate object file. You are missing a -o for building the objects, you need to not make an executable, compile only. (is that a -C option?) You do not need LIBS stuff for the object files. Im not sure you can have multiple C files to one object simply. I would expect to see one object file for each c file. Lots more improvements after that.

Comment: Looks like you should sort the contents of your code - you seem to have the same function declared in multiple files

Comment: Is that makefile exactly what you used? It seems to lack `-o` arguments for some targets ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the case, I have only used one definition for each function, and I have #ifndef, #define and #endif  in the .h files.

Comment: Do you mean that I should have -o for every target in the makefile, or only for the execution target

Comment: The error messages say otherwise - it is clearly saying that `Foo1_func1` is declared in "main.c" and "Foobar.c" and possibly elsewhere too

Comment: But my main.c has only includes for the folder1/Foobar1.h and folder2/Foo2.h  and in the main function is only printf("hello"); so i think it's somthing with linking files

Comment: So which file contains `Foo1_func1` then?

Comment: the decleration in Foo1.c , and Foobar1.c use Foo1.func1

Comment: Is creating a makefile something you are required to do?  If not, you may want to consider using an integrated development environment (IDE) such as _[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)_, or _[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)_.  In an IDE such as these, the work of the makefile is removed from the developer for the most part, thus removing its complexities from the effort of creating a project.

Comment: Because this is your post, all comments under it will automatically flag you as the recipient, but you need to specify explicitly who you are responding to.  So when replying to a specific commentor, you can direct your response to the right person by proceeding their moniker with an ampersand at the beginning of your reply, i.e. such as:  @ryyker - No, I am not required to use a makefile...

Comment: And which header file has the prototype for `Foo1_func1` that you're using to tell Foobar1.c about the function?

Answer (score 0):

You're running the executable (.o) without first compile the .c

```
run: main.o Foobar1.o Foo2.o
    $(CC) main.o Foobar1.o Foo2.o -o run $(LIBS)
```

[...]

And here you should rm using *.o, its safer.

```
clean:
    rm -rf *o run
```

The right order is:
1 - .h  (library) 
2 - .c (code)
3 - .o (executable)

Comment: That isn't running the executable - that's compiling it into an executable called "run"

Comment: Yep, I know. I just paste the wrong parts in the code.